# error in typedoc command, the angular document generator

Tags: angular, documentation, documentation-generation, typedoc

I wrote annotations and explanations in **typedoc** style all around my **angular** project.

Then I ran the following command to generate the documentation:

```
typedoc --name Sample Project --out ./docs/ --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --exclude node_modules --ignoreCompilerErrors app/
```

But the following error occures:

```
fs.js:1001
  binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), statValues);
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/roham/PhpstormProjects/Irantalent-Front4/Front'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:1001:11)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/application.js:145:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CliApplication.Application.expandInputFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/application.js:143:20)
    at CliApplication.bootstrap (/usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/cli.js:58:28)
    at CliApplication.Application (/usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/application.js:41:15)
    at new CliApplication (/usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/dist/lib/cli.js:35:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/bin/typedoc:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your command to :

```
typedoc --name Sample\ Project --out ./docs/ --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --exclude node_modules --ignoreCompilerErrors app/
```

(Add `\` before space)

This problem happens when you have space in your project name.